# Implementing an SMPP Server in Python

Tags: python, smpp

Does anyone know a tool to implement a Python SMPP server and some tips on how to proceed?

I found Pythomnic3k framework, but did not find material needed for me to use it as SMPP server ...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at jasmin sms gateway, it's pythonic and has smpp server implementation.